# Failed to create BI service instance in OBIEE12C installation @(Add default service instance step in BI configuration)

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, obiee

Followed These Steps to install OBIEE 12C:

1.Oracle database installation

2.Executing Fusion middleware jar file

3.Obiee 12c installation

4.Executing rcu bat file

5.Executing config bat file for Domain configuration

BI configuration failed in configuration process while executing config bat file which is mentioned in no.5 above

Error occured exactly in Add default service instance step in BI configuration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb6Ju.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing on a Windows desktop OS - stop it, it won't work because it wasn't, isn't and never will be supported.

https://dimensionality.ch/2017/05/06/installing-oracle-bi-on-windows-7-8-10/

Comment: I installed in windows server 2012.

Comment: Redo it but choose a different BAR file